# Save a part of GoogleMap for accessing offline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, saving-data

I found similar question, but not exactly what I want.
I want to allow user draw for example a rectangle on the map and when I know coordinates can I save this piece of map for further accessing it when user is using maps in offline mode?
Does anyone know how to do that or if it is possible at all?
Thanks for every good advice.

Comment: google maps does its own internal caching but it is nothing you can use or even trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of research on that subject and I am sure that google maps aren't really designed for offline browsing, unless you cache selected part of the map in google maps app. As you cannot currently save maps outside of GM app, then it is sure that you can't do more advanced things such as saving maps in custom shapes. Maybe they'll implement these features in the future..